# Vector of pointers of the base class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Bear with me. There are 3 classes. Person is the base class with name and age. Child is a derived class with a grade in school. Parent is another derived class who can have a child (yes or no)

Before we continue there are a couple of things I must point out:
This is an exercise which I thought up so I can practise inheritance a bit. The idea is to end up with a vector which contains pointers from the base class to the derived classes objects.

The "program" depends on the user entering correct  values, has no error checking and so on, but that is not the point of this exercise, so that is why I haven't done anything about it.

Feedback on how to fix the problems I am getting is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    string m_name;
    int m_age;
public:
    Person(string name, int age)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_age = age;
    }
    string get_name()
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    virtual void info() =0;
};

class Child : public Person
{
private:
    int m_grade;
public:
    Child(string name, int age, int grade) : Person(name, age)
    {
        m_grade = grade;
    }
    void info()
    {
        cout <<"I am a child. I go to the " << m_grade << " grade."<<endl;
    }
};

class Parent : public Person
{
private:
    bool m_child;
public:
    Parent(string name, int age, bool child) : Person(name, age)
    {
        m_child = child;
    }
    void info()
    {
        if(m_child == true)
        {
            cout << "I have a child." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I do not have a child" << endl;
        }
    }
};

vector create_list(const int& x)
{
    vector <Person> a;
    for(int a = 0; a < x; a++)
    {
        cout << "enter the name" << endl;
        string o;
        cin >> o;
        cout << "enter the age" << endl;
        int age;
        cin >> age;
        cout << "What would you like your person to be: a Child or a Parent?" << endl;
        string choice;
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == "Child")
        {
            cout << "enter it's grade" << endl;
            int grade;
            cin >> grade;
            Child* c  = new Child(o, age, grade);
            a.push_back(c);
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"enter if the parent has a child (yes/no)" << endl;
            string wc;
            cin >> wc;
            if(wc == "yes")
            {
                Parent* p = new Parent(o, age, true);
                  a.push_back(p);
            }
            else
            {
                Parent* p = new Parent(o, age, false);
                  a.push_back(p);
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "How many people would you like to create?" << endl;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
     vector<Person> a = create_list(x);
     a[0]->getname();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what problems you were getting!

Comment: `vector <Person> a;` should be `vector <Person *> a;`. But you shouldn't do this. You should either use a vector of *smart* pointers or a collection specifically designed to hold pointers, like `ptr_vector`.

Comment: What semantics do you want? For example, do you intend your vector to own the underlying objects? If the vector is copied, should both vectors contain pointers to the same underlying object or should the object be cloned?

Comment: Genuine feedback (of the kind that you don't need to unlearn when you grow up): `Person` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: The virtual destructor is something I hadn't considered. The program is weaking. I had forgotten all about that.

I am pretty new to c++, I didn't know about the existance of smart pointers until now, I will look them up. Thanks.
EDIT: as for the semantics, I simply want  for the vector to be able to hold it's derived classes, so I can store all created objects in it and use the vector to call functions from them.

Comment: @Bloodcount: But should the vector *own* the objects it holds pointers to? Or will something else manage their lifetime? When the vector is destroyed, should the objects be?

Comment: @David Schwartz
Yes, the vector will own the objects. I will trigger all functions from it. Yes, when the vector is destroyed, the objects should be Destroyed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are using the same variable name `a` for both `vector<Person>` and `int` in your `for loop`. So when you get to the line  `a.push_back(c);` the program will think that `a` is an integer, not a vector.

   Make your variable names unique.
2. As others have mentioned, your container is a `vector` of type `Person`, but you instantiate new derived classes of type `Child *` and `Parent *`, so your `vector` should be of type `Person*`.
3. On that same note, the return type of your function should read `vector<Person*>`
4. Although it is not necessary in this case since your application ends immediately, it is good practice to make sure every call to `new` corresponds to a call to `delete`. In that case you would write a `free_list` method which goes through and deletes each Person object pointed to in the list. Note that the vector itself requires no cleanup.